# problem in render using point light in panda 3D

Tags: python-3.x, panda3d

I am getting problems with point light render. What is the mistake? I am using Panda3D version 1.10.9. I first thought the texture might be transparent but it's JPG.

[image: Without Point Light]

[image: With Point Light]

[image: The Texture File]

[The 3D Model](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/resources/2393/earth-3d-model/)

What is causing the problem?

The code is as follows:

```
from panda3d.core import loadPrcFile
loadPrcFile("config/conf.prc")

from direct.showbase.ShowBase import ShowBase
# from panda3d.core import NodePath
from panda3d.core import PointLight, AmbientLight
from math import sin, cos


class MyGame(ShowBase):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.cam.setPos(0, -500, 0)
        self.setBackgroundColor(0,0,0)

        self.chara = self.loader.loadModel("planet_models/Earth")
        self.chara.setScale(0.2)
        self.chara.setPos(0, 0, -2.5)
        self.chara.reparentTo(self.render)
        self.charaNode = self.chara.node()

        self.sphere_light = self.loader.loadModel("models/misc/sphere")
        self.sphere_light.setScale(0.2)
        self.sphere_light.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.sphere_light.setPos(0, -600, 0)
        self.sphere_light.reparentTo(self.render)

        plight = PointLight("plight")
        plight.setColor((1, 1, 1, 1))
        self.plnp = self.sphere_light.attachNewNode(plight)
        # self.plightNodePath.setPos(2, 0, 0)
        plight.setAttenuation((1, 0, 0))
        self.chara.setLight(self.plnp)

        alight = AmbientLight("alight")
        alight.setColor((0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 1))
        alnp = self.render.attachNewNode(alight)
        self.chara.setLight(alnp)

        self.taskMgr.add(self.move_light, "move-light")

    def move_light(self, task):
        ft = globalClock.getFrameTime()
        self.sphere_light.setPos(cos(ft)*400, sin(ft)*400, 0)
        return task.cont

game = MyGame()
game.run()
```

with the prc file being

```
win-size 1280 720
window-title First Trial
show-frame-rate-meter true
show-scene-graph-analyzer-meter true
```

Comment: What *is* the problem?

Comment: If you need to include images, please link directly to the image files, not to web pages containing them.

Comment: I updated the question with pictures